# magento2 upload image frontend

Tags: magento2.3

i saved data but i want save upload image. But i have error. I have file phtml

```
Image: <input name="profile_image" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Send participant informations">
```

And i have file save.php

```
<?php

namespace Commercers\Course\Controller\Participant;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_participantFactory;

protected $_config;

protected $_uploaderFactory;

protected $_imageModel;


public function __construct(
    \Commercers\Course\Model\ParticipantFactory $participantFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Commercers\Course\Helper\Config $config,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \Commercers\Course\Model\Participant\Image $imageModel
) {
    $this->_participantFactory = $participantFactory;
    $this->_config = $config;
    $this->_uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    $this->_imageModel = $imageModel;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $data = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $imageName = '';

    if (!empty($data)) {
        $participantFactory = $this->_participantFactory->create();

        $imageName = $this->uploadFileAndGetName('profile_image', $this->_imageModel->getBaseDir(), $data);
        $participantFactory->addData($data);
        $participantFactory->setStatus($this->_config::STATUS_DEFAULT_PARTICIPANT);

        $participantFactory->setProfileImage($imageName);

        $participantFactory->save();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Participant saved !');

        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/course/participant/create');

        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}

public function uploadFileAndGetName($input, $destinationFolder, $data)
{
        if (isset($data[$input]['delete'])) {
            return '';
        } else {
            $uploader = $this->_uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $input]);
            $result = $uploader->save($destinationFolder);
            return $result['file'];
        }
    return '';
    }

}
```

Please help me with upload image!

Comment: what's error show???

Comment: it error with $uploader. Do you have any other way?

Comment: First, you should be add input type file at form and also add `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Comment: Yes, i have added

Comment: so you check this link --- https://code.vky.co.in/magento-2-custom-module-image-upload/